# Why can't I download Git and Github desktop on my system?

Tags: git, github, github-actions, git-diff, github-desktop

I am a new user to github, if anything, I only know how to log into git.

Lately I've been learning React Routing taught by Bob Ziroll on FreeCodeCamp's youtube page and I have gotten to the part where I have to install github desktop.

The Issue is whenever I try to download, it takes me to an error page, I also tried to download git and I still got that same error. I know it is not an issue with my laptop or internet cause the github site is working just fine. See image below:

[image: Git download error page]

Please help me. I feel this is the easiest way for me to learn how to automatically update my websites via git.
Please, Thank you.

P.S I dont know much of github or my way around it. Thank you

I tried to install git and github desktop and expected to install git and github desktop on my system

Comment: Do you know what time you tried that? GitHub had an incident earlier today which could have been a factor here: https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/xb30mby9fs5x

Comment: Hiiii. Thank you so much for this information. This was the issue and I have been able to download and install GitHub desktop. Thank you so so much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These are the official download pages:

- Git https://git-scm.com/downloads
- Github Desktop https://desktop.github.com/

Do those work?

Comment: Hi. Truly appreciate the links. It seemed GitHub had network issues last night. I have been able to download and install GitHub desktop.